# Error including multiple images in Latex

Tags: image, latex, texmaker

While compiling the following code

```
{\centering {\includegraphics[scale=.5]{splash.eps}} \caption{Splash Screen} \par}
\end{figure} 
Splash screen is an integral part and shows a tutorial of application.    
\begin{figure}[ht] 
{\centering {\includegraphics[scale=.5]{splashmore.eps}} \caption{Splash Screen 1} \par}
\end{figure}
```

The first image (i.e splash.eps) gets added properly when compiled. While trying to add the second one, compilation gives the following error.

```
! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in ./eps/splashmore.eps (no Bou
ndingBox).

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.16 ...\includegraphics[scale=.5]{splashmore.eps}
                                                  } \caption{Splash Screen 1...
```

What could be the problem?

Edit: The problem was with the image. I opened it with Gimp and saved it as .eps file and latter on used it with no troubles.

Comment: Try `pdflatex` instead of `latex`.

Comment: Geoff: pdflatex does not take eps graphics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be that `splashmore.eps` has no *Bounding Box* (like the error message says). You could either

- add the bounding box information manually (see [here](http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/postscript/bb.html) for a description of what a bounding box is and how to do that) or
- use a tool: Opening your file in a vector graphics editor and saving it (again) as `eps` could help, otherwise you could use [epstool](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/epstool.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try to add `width=5cm` as argument to includegraphics. Don't know if that is satisfactory though.